# How to check 2 newest tag at one tab?

Tags: support, tags, newest-questions

Is there any possibility to check newest question on 2 tags at the same time?

I know I can select 2 tags e.g. [php](/questions/tagged/php), [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), but I will see all questions which are tagged with both these tags.

I know I can select Unanswered tags, but this is also not a good solution.

What I am currently doing, opening several tabs with selected tags and newest questions. It's not comfortable.

Comment: Right now it's not possible. I tried a trick by adding "*" as ignored tag (which means ignore all tags) and choosing to hide questions with ignored tags, but it caused that all questions disappeared even those having favorite tags. If that behavior will be changed to that questions having a favorite tag are always displayed even if there is ignored tag this will be reasonable workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the search `[php][or][mysql]` and then filter using the `newest` tab.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Lance answer I can use 2 tags for filtering at the same time. But modification of query string is more convenient for me. You can do it this way:

```
questions/tagged/php+or+mysql
```